# Antd Tooltip gets stuck when component moves onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a button with an Antd tooltip, like this:

```
<Tooltip title="Some text">
  <button onClick={openNotes}><Icon icon="notes" /></button>
</Tooltip>
```

When you click the button, the `openNotes` function makes some other component appear on screen so it moves the Tooltip like 200px to the left.

This makes the tooltip get stuck unless you hover off it, then hover on, then off again.

Is there any solution to this? I tried setting the mouseLeave delay to 0 but it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 tooltip props that might help your problem, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but open prop might help as you can control with a state the visibilty of the tooltip. Moreover there is getPopupContainer prop that will make the tool ti relative to your trigger and not absolute for the whole page, this might work as well

```
const getPopupContainer = (parentNode) => parentNode.parentElement
```

just be sure that the css parent container has position: relative.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a setTimeout in openNotes to delay showing the component.